# Correlation matrix categorical variables

Tags: r, correlation

What is the correct way to build a correlation matrix with only categorical variables? And in the case of a mix between categorical and continuous?

In the case of only continuous variables Pearson correlation can be used but it cannot be applied when there are categorical variables.

It also would be helpful a piece of R code to do it.

Comment: Hello, are you lookin for something like [Cramér's V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V)?

Comment: @zxc you need to recode categorical to integer type, e.g. v1 <- as.integer(v1)

Comment: @PsychometStats That solution is completely arbitrary--it depends on the underlying coding, which typically is automatically determined by the software--and likely does not produce the kind of information being sought.

Comment: @VincentGuillemot I have been checking it and what I want was something like this (https://vizerybusiness.files.wordpress.com/2019/01/cm1.png) but it seems that Pearson correlation is only defined for continuous variables. One solution is using Cramer as you propose and the other one is label encoding the variables. My question now is: it's correct to label encode if there is not an order relationship between the levels.

Comment: @whuber See my last comment.

Comment: That reflects my original understanding of your problem.  However, you need to edit your post to make it clear you are looking for that kind of statistical advice rather than just for software to produce some kind of correlation matrix.

Comment: @whuber Edited. Is it now more clear?

Comment: Pearson correlation isn't restricted to continuous variables. It measures linearity of association and can be applied easily to e.g. counted variables. It can also be applied to ranks; that is also called Spearman (rank) correlation. Whether it is a good thing to use is often trickier to state or decide but having continuous variables is not necessary. What is clear is that Pearson correlation of arbitrary codes e.g. 1 for prefer cat 2 for prefer dog 3 for like neither produces meaningless nonsense. What is open is where you found that stated.